# JavaScript event handler race

Tags: javascript, button, textfield, onblur, onmouseup

If I have a text field with a registered `onblur` event handler and a button with a registered `onmouseup` event handler, which one of those two functions will run sooner and why?

To make my question clearer, let's suppose the focus is currently on the text field and I want to click on the button.

Will there be any difference between various Internet browsers?

**Edit**

Especially tricky seems the `onmousedown` event when it's registered with the button, whilst the text field has an `onblur` event registered with it.

Comment: Note: *In contrast to MSIE--in which almost all kinds of elements receive the blur event--almost all kinds of elements on Gecko browsers do NOT work with this event.* Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Text fields, however, do.

Comment: My mistake, I meant `onmouseup` event. :-)

Comment: the onblur will run first as focusables get blurred when onmousedown on other elements.

Comment: You can test it out by having console log on both events, see which one fires first

Comment: @Patrick Evans: And what if I register an `onmousedown` event handler for the button?

Comment: onmousedown would have to as otherwise it wouldnt know that there needed to be a blur event.

Comment: @Patrick Evans: Great comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-blur) `blur` must be fired when focus leaves the element (after taking focus away), but I don't see any explicit statement about when that must occur relative to the event causing the focus to be moved away.

Certainly the `mouseup` will happen much later (in computer terms), as first you have to `mousedown`.

I would have expected `blur` to fire prior to even the `mousedown`, but I would have been wrong: According to [experimentation](http://jsbin.com/ukavuj/1), `mouseup` is after, but `mousedown` is before. I tested that using Chrome 26, Opera 12.15, Firefox 20, IE8, and IE9 — and if you can get those five to agree on a behavior, it's likely to be consistent in others... :-) My suspicion is that this is because if you prevent the default action of the `mousedown`, focus never moves away from the text field: [Example](http://jsbin.com/ukavuj/2). (This behavior is consistent across *four* of those five browsers, with IE8 not preventing the focus change — meaning IE7 and 6 probably don't, either.) So while it seems odd, it does kind of make sense.

As always, test with the browsers you intend to support.

Comment: Yea, onmousedown fires before blur, in my chrome as well.

Answer (score -1):

Just save the timestamp when starting

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
```

and then

```
var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
```

into the handler.

Comment: Not quite related. `console.log()` on both events already did the job.